# Powershell - I want to return only empty records from ipconfig /displaydns

Tags: powershell

The subject is my ultimate goal. Using Powershell I have managed to return the contents of "ipconfig /displaydns" formatted into a table but I used some publicly posted code and I am new to powershell so I don't fully understand how it all works. The problem with what I am using is that it only returns the results that begin with the text "Record Name". This means that any entry that has no A record or where a record doesn't exist will not be returned. I'm using this code to try and get these records:

```
Function Get-FailedDNSClientCache{ 
    Invoke-Expression "IPConfig /DisplayDNS" | Select-String -Pattern "-----" -Context 2,1 |

        ForEach-Object{
            "" + $_.Context.PreContext[1]
            "" + $_.Line
            "" + $_.Context.Postcontext[0]
            "" + $_.Context.PreContext[2]
           }
       }
```

The code above gives me some output that looks like this:

```
pagead.l.doubleclick.net
----------------------------------------
No records of type AAAA

s0-2mdn-net.l.google.com
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : s0-2mdn-net.l.google.com    

www.redditstatic.com
----------------------------------------
No records exist

s0-2mdn-net.l.google.com
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : s0-2mdn-net.l.google.com
```

I've been trying all the different filtering methods I have found but I end up returning no data, null fields or I filter out just the text line that starts with "Record Name" but not the entire record. I think the problem is that I need to create each returned record as an object rather than each line but my attempts at that have failed as well. I'd basically like for my output to look like this:

```
pagead.l.doubleclick.net
----------------------------------------
No records of type AAAA

www.redditstatic.com
----------------------------------------
No records exist
```

I've seen bits and pieces of my question answered throughout the forum and I have tried most of the solutions provided but I think I am not understanding something fundamental allowing me to put it all together correctly. Please keep in mind I am truly trying to understand what I am doing so the more information the better.
TIA

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned...Mostly Windows 7 desktop environment. The Get-DNSClientCache cmdlet isn't available and the function I used probably isn't written the same way so the status query fails.

Comment: The regex is promising but if I am understanding it correctly it is looking for a match to "No Records". I've been trying to find a list of possible outcomes when there is no record in the DNS cache and I have seen multiple variations of data in that location. Where could I put a NOT LIKE "Record Name"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Get-DnsClientCache cmdlet and pass in the status flag you wish to search for.  For example:

```
Get-DnsClientCache -Status NotExist
```

Or

```
Get-DnsClientCache -Status NoRecords
```

If you don't have this function, you can create your own based on https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ad12dc1c-b0c7-44d6-97c7-1a537b0b4fef

The code for the above cited function is:

```
Function Get-DNSClientCache{ 
$DNSCache = @() 

Invoke-Expression "IPConfig /DisplayDNS" | 
Select-String -Pattern "Record Name" -Context 0,5 | 
    %{ 
        $Record = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
        Name=($_.Line -Split ":")[1] 
        Type=($_.Context.PostContext[0] -Split ":")[1] 
        TTL=($_.Context.PostContext[1] -Split ":")[1] 
        Length=($_.Context.PostContext[2] -Split ":")[1] 
        Section=($_.Context.PostContext[3] -Split ":")[1] 
        HostRecord=($_.Context.PostContext[4] -Split ":")[1] 
        } 
        $DNSCache +=$Record 
    } 
    return $DNSCache 
}
```

Either of these methods will return an object that you can manipulate further as needed.

Comment: This is the function I am using to get the DNS Cache. As you say it is great for manipulating into a table that is much easier to read when doing analysis. However, it uses the string "Record Name" as a starting reference point and pulls it along with the next five lines of text for the remainder of the parsing. The text I need does not contain that string so it doesn't see it. Basically, I want the opposite of what this returns. i tested the switches you recommended to be sure and it returned the rest of the cache I was already getting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where-Object` to filter on matches where the `PostContext[0]` value contains the string "No records":

```
Function Get-FailedDNSClientCache{ 
Invoke-Expression "IPConfig /DisplayDNS" | Select-String -Pattern "-----" -Context 2,1 | Where-Object {$_.Context.Postcontext[0] -like "*No records*"} |ForEach-Object {
        "" + $_.Context.PreContext[1]
        "" + $_.Line
        "" + $_.Context.Postcontext[0]
        "" + $_.Context.PreContext[2]
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple regex:

- oneliner

  > ([regex]'(?s)(\S+)\n\s+-+\s+(.+?)\n').matches((ipconfig /displayDNS) -join "`n") | ?{ $_.groups[2].value -notlike 'Record Name*' } | %{ $orphans = @{} } { $orphans[$_.groups[1].value] = $_.Groups[2].value } { $orphans }
- more readable, using [PS2 SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx)

  ```
  $output = (ipconfig /displayDNS) -join "`n"
  $rx = [regex]'(?s)(\S+)\n\s+-+\s+(.+?)\n'
  $orphansSorted = [Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[string,string]]::new()

  forEach ($match in $rx.matches($output)) {
      $url = $match.groups[1].value
      $msg = $match.groups[2].value
      if ($msg -notlike 'Record Name*') {
          $orphansSorted[$url] = $msg
      }
  }
  $orphansSorted
  ```

Output:

```
Key                                          Value                  
---                                          -----                  
mpa.one.microsoft.com                        No records of type AAAA
my.router                                    No records exist
onlineconfigservice.ubi.com                  No records of type AAAA
static3.cdn.ubi.com                          No records of type AAAA
ubisoft-orbit.s3.amazonaws.com               No records of type AAAA
ubisoft-orbit-savegames.s3.amazonaws.com     No records of type AAAA
```